# CD Micro Services Support on cloud platforms

Tags: microservices, docker, service-fabric

What is the official support position for Content Delivery Microservices on cloud platforms?
We see how to deploy microservices as Windows Services and how this can be expanded to provide High Availability using a load balancer, but we want to implement a more robust scalable solution using Docker or Azure service Fabric.
Other partners have built Docker based solutions and we are trialing Azure Service Fabric solutions.
The client wants to know if these solutions are approved and supported by SDL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official answer from SDL support

> Case 00308815    12 October 2017 11:56
>
> Subject: CD Micro Services Support on cloud platforms
>
> "As long as you are building containers from our on-premise artifacts,
>   then we support them. In a future release, we are planning to provide
>   pre-built docker images of all of our services for customers wishing
>   to use them."

Answer (score 4):

For an official answer you probably need to go through official channels (Customer Support).

Judging by the [Pre-Requisites for Content Delivery Microservices](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-C8DF0157-CB44-4929-8391-3558774C31F8) you need Java 8 and a supported OS - no word about Docker or Azure Service Fabric.